# DynDns and localserver

Tags: router, email, pop3, dyndns

I bind dyndns host to my local computer. My router - Zyxel P-600. In my router settings in DynDns tab i set my accaunt dyndns settings. I 110 port forward. Then i set up pop3 server.

I try to connect with telnet to my server. But telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

nslookup mydomain:

Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   shk.dyndns-mail.com
Address: 95.59.96.111

What's wrong? Maybe i must something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Internet work:

```
$ telnet 95.59.96.111 110
Trying 95.59.96.111...
Connected to 95.59.96.111.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK POP3 server ready
```

possible forwarding does not work in a local network.

Comment: Yes, it's don't work in local network. @ooshro, thank you very much for test